# Terraform giving error for new AWS new regions (af-south-1,eu-south-1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, region

I am facing issue while creating resources in aws account using terraform script (0.11 version)

changes in main.tf file =>

```
provider "aws" {
alias = "af-south-1"
region = "af-south-1"
}

module "af-south-1-module" {
  source = "./modules"
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.af-south-1"
  }
 aws_region= "af-south-1"
 should_run= "${contains(var.region_list, "af-south-1")}"
 customer_id= "${var.customer_id}"
 dns_prefix= "${var.dns_prefix_flowlogs}"
 iam_for_lambda_arn= "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
 aws_account_id= "${local.aws_account_id}"
 iam_for_vpc_flow_arn= "${aws_iam_role.avid_vpc_flow_role.arn}"
 }
```

changes in **vars.tf** file =>

```
    variable "region_list" {
    type = "list"
    default = ["us-west-1",
    "us-west-2",
    "us-east-1",
    "eu-north-1",
    "af-south-1"]
   }
```

I am getting following error while running "terraform apply" command

**Error: Error refreshing state: 2 error(s) occurred:**

- provider.aws.eu-south-1: Invalid AWS Region: eu-south-1
- provider.aws.af-south-1: Invalid AWS Region: af-south-1

**Note:**

1. Region is enabled in AWS account
2. Same code is working for other regions in region_list.

Comment: Is your Terraform version updated to the most recent version?

Comment: @mokugo-devops
Requirement is to support creation of resources using both 0.11 and 0.12 version
It is working for 0.12 but failing for 0.11

Comment: Did you check that all the services you use in the Terraform are available in those regions?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error for the region "eu-south-1" which I did not see in your code.
I will suggest you to check the region specified in your **.aws/credentials** file in your system.
Also check your **aws provider version**, terraform 0.11 doesn't support higher versions as it is supported in 0.12 version.
Some time **template verssion** difference also creates issues to terraform to work.

Comment: Waseem
Regarding aws provider version
while running terraform init command I am getting following message
The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
**so the latest version was installed.**

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the
corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings
suggested below.

* provider.aws: version = "~> 2.43"

Comment: You can add ```provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  version = "~> 1.52.0"
}```